# Can't download flexica cms

Tags: php, content-management-system, yii, download

Yii cms `flexicacms.com` website disabled the downloading facility by disabling sending activation letter.

Anyone have backup of this CMS please share with me with a download link.

At this site this question exist and answer is pointed to depositfiles. But there are some server updates and it doesn't allow to download needable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download from this link:
http://depositfiles.com/files/3zmnru11w